# Quero exemplo do por quê substituir ' por '' e \ por \\ para parâmetros de um query é perigoso

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, segurança, sql-injection

Eu vejo muitos posts sobre este assunto, porém não vejo nenhum exemplo que tem cabimento para este meu caso.

```
function sanitize($value)
{
    $val = str_replace("'", "''", $value);
    $val = str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $val);

    return $val;
}
```

A query ficaria `mysqli_query($conn,"insert into tabela (Nome) values ('".sanitize($ipt)."')")`
Considerando que até mesmo int entrará neste procedimento acima e considerando que todas as querys serão escritas EXATAMENTE desta maneira, com parâmetros demarcados com '(aspas simples), qual input seria capaz de quebrar a segurança e causar um injection?

Comment: Se existe erro ou não eu não posso afirmar, mas chutaria que talvez exista. A melhor alternativa seria usar o `mysqli_real_escape_string($ipt)`. Você pode usar `prepared statements` (isso é, usar o `mysqli_prepare ()` e depois o `mysqli_bind_param()`) essa solução pode ser mais difícil de ser aplicada, exigindo mais alterações. Acredito que isso será melhor do que tentar "reinventar" a roda.

Answer (score 2):

No seu exemplo a inserção realmente está escapando os caracteres a fim de evitar injection. Ok.

O grande problema está mesmo na forma que você irá fazer:

> Considerando que até mesmo int entrará neste procedimento acima e
>   considerando que todas as querys serão escritas EXATAMENTE desta
>   maneira [...]

De que forma você irá garantir isso com extrema certeza? Se você esquecer o `sanitize` em uma única *query*, como você irá descobrir isso? Basta um único lugar e seu site estará vulnerável.

Se algo tem chance de dar errado, isso VAI dar errado... Então pra que dar chance ao azar?

Se a linguagem oferece formas de evitar esse tipo de problemas de forma nativa, qual o problema de usar essa solução?

Temos os *prepared statments* no `mysqli`, no `PDO`, onde o sanitize da query é feita de forma assertiva e transparente que chega a ser incoerente não utilizá-las caso conheça da sua existência.

A manutenção do código também fica mais simples. Veja um exemplo:

```
$connection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1', 'db', 'pass');

$stment = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO user VALUES (:id, :name, :idade);');
$stment->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stment->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
$stment->bindParam(':idade', $idade, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$id = 1;
$name = 'Joao';
$idade = 18;

$stment->execute();
```

O código acima não está mais claro que o de baixo?

```
$connection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1', 'db', 'pass');

$id = 1;
$name = 'Joao';
$idade = 18;

$connection->query("INSERT INTO user VALUES ('" . sanitize($id) . "', '" . sanitize($name) "','" . sanitize($idade) . "');");
```